# Debug failing SFTP transfers ("forced close")

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, sftp

I have a user who regularly connects to a server via SFTP and reads and writes files. This has been going on for years without issue, until a couple of weeks ago where we're now seeing sporadic failures.

Server is CentOS, user in question is chrooted to their home directory. There have been no major configuration changes to this machine for a long time. Almost all files are < 3mb.

I'm 99% sure this has to be something their end, but I want to make sure I've checked everything I can this end.

I enabled INFO logging of internal-sftp so I can see a little more output. I'm seeing "forced close" and "forced closedir" on both reads and writes, often after they've successfully read/written other files in the same session.

Server has loads of free space, no storage quotas etc are set up. I tested uploading a large volume of data with their account and had no issues.

Is there any other debugging I can do from our end of the connection that could make this picture clearer? There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of advice out there about this!

EDIT: Logs as requested...

```
sshd[6215]: Accepted password for <USER> from xx.xx.xx.xx port xxx ssh2
sshd[6215]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <USER> by (uid=0)
sshd[6432]: subsystem request for sftp
sshd[6433]: session opened for local user <USER> from [xx.xx.xx.xx]
sshd[6433]: open "/Inventory/Inventory_1787_20190926_2001.csv" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666
sshd[6433]: close "/Inventory/Inventory_1787_20190926_2001.csv" bytes read 0 written 18258
sshd[6433]: open "/Inventory/Inventory_1845_20190926_2002.csv" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666
sshd[6433]: forced close "/Inventory/Inventory_1845_20190926_2002.csv" bytes read 0 written 0
sshd[6433]: session closed for local user <USER> from [xx.xx.xx.xx]
sshd[6215]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user <USER>
```

Comment: *"forced close"* means that there were pending opened file/directory handles at the time the connection was closed. More useful would be, to know what are previous/following log records.

Comment: Edited to add a failure log. I should also note we have another remote user dropping files in their own chrooted directory without issue.